# sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Mapper '...' has no property '...'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two classes, `TrialIdentifier` and `TimeCourse`

TimeCourse has an instance variable containing a TrialIdentifier, and I am trying to setup a foreign key relationship between the two.

in TrialIdentifier

```
__tablename__ = 'trial_identifiers'

relationships = relationship('TimeCourse', 
                             back_populates = 'trial_identifier', uselist = False)
```

in TimeCourse

```
__tablename__ = 'time_course'

trial_identifier_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('trial_identifiers.id'))
trial_identifier = relationship('TrialIdentifier', back_populates = 'relationships')`
```

If I name the variable `trial_identifier` in `TimeCourse` the following error is thrown:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Mapper 'Mapper|TimeCourse|time_course' has no property 'trial_identifier'

If I name it anything else, everything works fine. The entire package is built on the `TimeCourse().trial_identifier` so I would like to avoid refactoring it if possible. Or at least understand this behavior.

Answer (score 8):

trial_identifier was a private variable, defined as `_trial_identifier`

Either removing the setters and getters, or replacing

```
trial_identifier = relationship('TrialIdentifier', back_populates = 'relationships')`
```

with

```
_trial_identifier = relationship('TrialIdentifier', back_populates = 'relationships')`
```

solved the problem

Answer (score 7):

Also, you can use an alternative way to solve this problem. Just use `backref` instead of `back_populates`. It works for me:

In TimeCourse:

```
trial_identifier = relationship('TrialIdentifiers', backref = 'time_course')
```

More info you can find at [SQLAlchemy docs.](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html)