# SQLAlchemy, fields for private variables

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am using a class with property and setter decorators. I'm wondering why I must reference the private variable name `_child` instead of `child` in the example below. Shouldn't I indirectly access `_child` through the setter/getter when accessing `child`

Minimal example below:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child = relationship('Child', back_populates='parent')
    child_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('child.id'))
    def __init__(self):
        self._child= Child()

    @property
    def child(self):
        return self._child

    @child.setter
    def child(self, child):
        print('child set')
        self._child= child

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    parent = relationship('Parent', back_populates='child')

    def __init__(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    child = Child()
    parent = Parent()
    parent.child = child
```

This throws the following error:
`sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Mapper 'Mapper|Parent|parents' has no property 'child'`

If I replace

```
child = relationship('Child', back_populates='parent')
# and
parent = relationship('Parent', back_populates='child')
```

with

```
_child = relationship('Child', back_populates='parent')
# and
parent = relationship('Parent', back_populates='_child')
```

everything works

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. If you write `child = relationship...` you'll shadow your `child` property.

Comment: I assume you cannot have `child = relationship..` and must have `_child = relationship..`. I tried the former and got an error described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139767/sqlalchemy-exc-invalidrequesterror-mapper-has-no-property

Comment: You'll need to provide a minimal example. It's unclear whether you're shadowing the `property` with the `relationship` or vice versa. In either case they conflict with each other because they have the same name. Again, not clear on what your actual question is.

Comment: Added a minimal working example.

Answer (score 0):

You're shadowing the relationship `child` with a `property` of the same name. It's the same as if you didn't have the relationship at all, so `back_populates="child"` cannot find a relationship called `child`, because it doesn't exist.

Judging by your example alone, you don't need the `property` at all.